# I could not able to add my custom css and javascript files in functions.php

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

Guys I'am trying add my custom CSS in wordpress.I have used wp_enqueue_style() for each and every css file but it is not working anymore. Have a look at my functions.php file.

```
function theme_add_bootstrap() { 
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-css1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/mystyle1.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-css2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/mystyle2.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-css3', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/nav.css');

    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '3.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_add_bootstrap' );
```

Comment: And where is said "functions.php" file ?

Comment: And I updated my rating as I should! :)

Comment: Where have you placed your files? Are you using a child theme, and are the files placed in that directory? `get_template_directory_uri()` returns the path for the parent theme while `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` returns the path of the child theme.

Answer (score 0):

It really should work if you don't have child theme.

If you have a child theme then it will not work since `get_template_directory_uri()` will look for parent theme folder.

Where as `get_stylesheet_directory_url()` will only work since it will look for child theme directory files.

If you don't have child theme then please set a priority to `add_action()`

`add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_add_bootstrap', 10 );`

Hope this works for you.

Thank You